# What is the linq equivalent of the below sql query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
select Productid from categories where `categoryname` in `('abc','def','ghi')`;
```

I have tried this:

```
var res = from catg in db.Categories where catg.CategoryId.ToString().Contains(SelectedProducts) select catg;
```

But this doesnt seem to work...

Comment: Your SQL statement says `categoryname` but the LINQ says `CategoryId` - is this intended?

Comment: var res = from catg in db.Categories where catg.categoryname.ToString().Contains(SelectedProducts) select catg;

Comment: In that case your LINQ is at odds with the SQL, they do different things. See the two answers on how to replicate an IN statement in LINQ. I am puzzled at CategoryID.ToString() - if it's an integer, you'll have better performance comparing to a list of integers. See @smartDev answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `SelectedProducts` is an array of product ids (integers):

```
var cats = db.Categories.Where(o => SelectedProducts.Contains(o.CategoryId));
var pids = cats.Select(o => o.ProductId);
```

Reason: SQL `IN` operator is implemented oppositely in `LINQ` to SQL. The question highlights a common mistake in LINQ developers trying to translate from SQL, expecting an `[attribute] [operator] [set]` syntax.

Using an abstract set language we can highlight syntax differences

- SQL uses a "Element `is included` in Set" syntax
- LINQ uses a "Set `contains` Element" syntax

So any `IN` clause must be reverted using the `Contains` operator. It will translate to `attribute IN (SET)` anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Contains` on *SelectedProducts*

```
var res = from catg in db.Categories where 
SelectedProducts.Contains(catg.categoryname) select catg.Productid;
```

Using method notation

```
var res = db.Categories.Where(catg => SelectedProducts
            .Contains(catg.categoryname)).Select(catg.Productid);
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalence of a SQL IN with [IEnumerable.Contains()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx):

```
var res = from catg in db.Categories 
          where new[] {"abc","def","ghi"}.Contains(catg.categoryname) 
          select catg.Productid
```

Or lambda

```
db.Categories.Where(x => new[] {"abc","def","ghi"}.Contains(x.categoryname)).Select(c => c.ProductId);
```